# DEV 501 - Apex Integration Scenario

Tags: apex, dev501

The official link for 501 Preparation

http://certification.salesforce.com/developers

In the study guide .pdf for Advanced developers, where they list down the topics of study for 501 preparation  they have mentioned the following as one of the topics .

***"Describe use cases for Force.com code in an integration scenario"***

But in the same .pdf they have mentioned that ***"A candidate for this exam is not expected to be able to administer any standard Salesforce applications, develop integrations using the Force.com SOAP and REST APIs, or publish or consume Force.com App Exchange packages."***

I don't have knowledge about exposing Apex as either SOAP or REST (as we use TIBCO for most of our integration reqs) so should I have to know about exposing Apex as either SOAP or REST as well for this 501 exam ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appeared for DEV 501 multiple choice question in May 2014. There was only one question related to use case for integration scenario. DEV 501 multiple choice question exam does not have questions related to SOAP or REST based API. So no need to worry. You should prepare for other exam topics in detail.

Answer (score 7):

Having recently passed all three parts of the 501 certification, I would say that yes there is some you need to know about Apex integrations.

- you do not need to know the SOAP or REST integration for Salesforce customization. As in, you will not need to study the Tooling API or Metadata API
- you do need to know how you would write Apex code to integrate with an outside system, at least at a high level. That means understanding @future methods and limitations, HTTP callouts and limitations, and Batch Apex.

With all of that though, you only will need it for the multiple choice exam. The written portions will not (at least I have not seen it) include external integrations. Understand that you may not get any questions on the multiple choice about future Apex while someone else may get 10. It really is just luck for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get assignment related to Integration.

I have recently submitted my assignment.My assignment was related to Integration.

The Integration will not be a complex one but its good to have some knowledge about REST & SOAP before appearing for this exam.